# How to use value from URL and request in Django DetailView?

Tags: django, url, if-statement, detailview

I have a DetailView in django views.py where I want to be able to compare the pk value from the url ex:localhost:8000/myapp/details/3/ and the request.user.id with an if statement.

There is nothing more than the following few lines of code in the view:

```
class UserDetail(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'details.html'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have to overide def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): and you will get pk = self.kwargs['pk']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside a DetailView you have access to `self.request`, `self.args` and `self.kwargs`!

ref.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

In your urls.py add something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #...
    url(r'^details/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', UserDetail.as_view()),
]
```

and your UserDetail can now access `request.user.id` and pk by `self.kwargs['pk']` (see reference above: kwargs is name-based, so that you can access it by `self.kwargs['name']` and self.args is position-based, so you would access it by self.args[0]).

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to manipulate the queryset of the DetailView, to only return the data if the current logged in user is trying to access his page. 
If this is true, then you should override get_queryset in your class, like that:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.kwargs['pk'] == self.request.user.id:
        return Profile.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
    else:
        return Profile.objects.none()
```

Comment: I used the following codes in the UserDetail class and I get a NameError: name 'self' is not defined......

if self.kwargs['pk'] != request.user.id:
        queryset = Profile.objects.none()

Comment: Did you maybe forget to pass self to your function? Like that: def myFunction(self):

Comment: I added to my original answer, check if this helps out more.